# Additional key binding for RefTeX to add new bibliography entry

Tags: key-bindings, reftex-mode

Nowadays I often insert `@Online` entries into my bibliography files.

Unfortunately, the RefTeX doesn't have the Online-Entry bound to any key by default.

I tried to add something like

```
;; I often use the "@Online" entry in my bibliographies.
;; Unfortunately, no key binding was defined by default.  I think C-c
;; C-e C-o would be a good choice and is still unused.
(define-key reftex-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-e C-O") 'bibtex-Online)
```

Running `eval-last-sexp` (bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd>) gave no error, but said `bibtex-Online` as expected.

What is my mistake?

**EDIT**

After having Emacs restarted, the key binding worked, but unfortunately (again!) not in a buffer with a bibliography file!  I was working on my LaTeX file and when I tried to insert a new environment by pressing <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd>, but instead of asking which environment I was about to insert, Emacs waited for the next keypress an ah voilà, after completing the session with <kbd>C-o</kbd> Emacs most happily inserted an template for an Online document (`@Online{...}`) into my LaTeX buffer.  Yet, still, the key binding didn't work in the bibliography buffer :-(

Comment: Reg. your sentence: _I think `C-c C-e C-o` would be a good choice and is still unused._  From [Emacs lisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html#Key-Binding-Conventions): Don't define `C-c letter` as a key in Lisp programs. Sequences consisting of `C-c` and a letter (either upper or lower case) are reserved for users; they are the **only** sequences reserved for users, so do not block them.

Comment: @ArashEsbati I consider myself a user, but your hint doesn't apply..  Quoting from your quote: "`C-c` and a letter (either upper or lower case)" would match e.g. `C-c o` or `C-c O`.  But I used `C-c C-e C-o`, which shouldn't match?  At least, I choose it, as **all** of the bibliography entries are starting with   `C-c C-e` as a prefix.  So i guess, it can't be that false?

Comment: My hint was meant to say: Stay in the user realms with keybindings.  Or approach `bibtex` maintainer to possibly add your binding to the mode.

Comment: @ArashEsbati thank you.  `C-c o` and `C-c O` are already defined by me (and even more important) well trained to me.  I understand your hint, that my personal keybinding could rise a conflict, if the `bibtex-mode`-maintainer decide, to add exact this keybinding to their package?

Comment: I was more thinking about `C-c C-e C-o` and not `C-c [oO]` `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Hurray.  I found my mistake.

Instead of

```
(define-key reftex-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-e C-O") 'bibtex-Online)
```

one has to write

```
(define-key bibtex-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-e C-O") 'bibtex-Online)
```

You have to use `bibtex-mode-map`, not its brother `reftex-mode-map`.